# To develop a lib with SSO on twitter

Tags: twitter, oauth, single-sign-on

I want to develop a lib for twitter which can achieve SSO and can display the name of app which uses this lib during APP authorization.
I know you can do this in apple using twitter framework, but I want to do this in Non-Apple platforms.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this leveraging the OAuth capabilities available from Twitter.  You could leverage a user's Web session if they are already signed in to twitter.com.  See: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth

Any native (mobile) application SSO capabilities would depend on what the Twitter native application makes available.  I'm not aware of any - but Facebook does offer such features: https://www.facebook.com/help/mobile/singlesignon

Comment: Thanks Scott, I know that persisting access token and web session would work, but my question is, is it possible for any app to display  its name while authorization, once login is done.for instance if login is already done (through a twitter app), I would store the access token, now if Application A wants to tweet, it wont be needing authentication, but how would I be able to display App A's name while permitting it since access token generated earlier was for the before mentioned twitter app. Is there any way to generate an access token which is independent of the app